# Proper way to clear collection view in MVVM

Tags: swift, mvvm, uicollectionview

I have a collection view driven by a view model. When user logs out, I want to clear the view model and the collection view. But  program crashes whenever I tried to call `collectionView?.reload()` when the view model is cleared: `request for number of items in section 6 when there are only 0 sections in the collection view`.

```
class ViewModel {

    private var childVMs: [ChildViewModel]()

    var numberOfSections { return childVMs.count }

    func numberOfItems(inSection section: Int) {
        return childVMs[section].numberOfItems
    }

    func clear() {
        childVMs.removeAll()
    }
    ...
}

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    let vm = ViewModel()

    func logout() {
        vm.clear()
        collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return vm.numberOfSections
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return vm.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
    }

    ...
}
```

I noticed that when program crashes, `numberOfSections(in)` returns 0 as expected and `collectionView(_, numberOfItemsInSection)` is not even called. Any thoughts on where might went wrong?

Comment: it's just a `UICollectionViewController`, added

Comment: Is `logout()` called on the main thread?

Comment: Please answer Mike Taverne's question.

Comment: Yeah, say `UIButton.addtarget(target: self, #selector(logout))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It turns out the problem is in my custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. In it, I called `let numberOfItems = collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: section)`, where `section` is determined by my data source. So I added a guard statement before and everything works out beautifully:

```
guard let numberOfSections = collectionView?.numberOfSections,
            numberOfSections > section else { return }
```

There is no way you all could have figured this out, and I totally didn't expect that's where the problem was. So I just want to post this here for whoever might experience similar problem with `reloadData()` in the future ---- remember to check your custom layout!

Answer (score 0):

Because you have removed all ChildViewModel, childVMs is empty array, before calling function numberOfItems(inSection section: Int). It make your app crash because you get an element in empty array: childVMs[section], childVMs.count is safe for empty array.